# Selecting a field in Protractor

Tags: protractor

```
<hs-details-item>
        <hs-label>Location</hs-label>
        <hs-value-block>
            <hs>
                <hs-text-box ng-class="{'disabled': isAmenityPosting }" class="required" input-control="{title:'Location', okCallback:setJobSite, value:jobSiteName,
                      autocomplete:{ values:getJobSiteList, reload: true }, ss:'location'}">
                    <i class="icon-room"></i><span hs-placeholder="Select Location" class="ng-binding"></span>
                </hs-text-box>
            </hs>
            <hs>
                <!-- ngIf: isBarcodeShow() --><hs-button ng-class="{'disabled': soCreating }" class="barcode-special-btn smaller ng-scope" ng-if="isBarcodeShow()" hs-gesture="{handler:startScan, param: onBarcodeScanCompleted}"><i class="icon-br-code"></i></hs-button><!-- end ngIf: isBarcodeShow() -->
            </hs>
        </hs-value-block>
    </hs-details-item>
```

Scenario: click on “Location” field...
What would be the best way to come up with a command in Protractor to select "location" field from the above Snippet Code? 
Can it be done by not using Xpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple options here. A sort of a non-welcomed, but short and readable way, would be to use an XPath expression and check the preceding `label`:

```
var locationTextBox = element(by.xpath("//hs-label[. = 'Location']/following::hs-text-box"));
locationTextBox.click();
```

Comment: @ alecxe, Is there a downside using Xpath to come up with the automation script?

Comment: @Kevin well, [Protractor Style Guide](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/style-guide.md#never-use-xpath) dictates not to use XPath, but, from my point of view, it's too strong of a statement and should rather be a recommendation since there are certain use cases when it is appropriate, like in this case.

Comment: Xpath is the slowest out of all locator methods (and the most brittle/hard to maintain as your app continues to evolve), though it is necessary in cases where you don't have anything specific to grab the element.

Comment: @Kevin you could have also used `$("hs-text-box[input-control*=location]");`, but I'm not sure this uniquely identifies this element.